# Day and Month getting mixed up in Twig |date_modify

Tags: php, date, twig

I'm using the following code to add various dates to my website. I'm wanting to add a menu  which displays -3 Days, + 1 Days etc.

I'm currently using the following code but I'm having issues: `{{urlparam.depdate|date_modify("-3 day")|date("d/m/Y")}}`

The day and month keep getting mixed up despite setting the date format in my Twig template.

Example:
https://myurl.com/?results=Y&depdate=20/08/2019&flex=0 
is outputting as 08/17/2019 however it should be outputting as 17/08/2019 (DD/MM/YYYY)

I've tried swapping DD/MM round but this obviously throws up errors when the day goes beyond 12 as it thinks its a month.

```
{{urlparam.depdate|date_modify("-3 day")|date("d/m/Y")}}
```

Any solution or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you aren't getting an exception when using `20/08/2019`, as this is a invalid date for the given format, `DateTime` expect `MM/DD/YYYY` when using this format as seen [here](https://ideone.com/mP26xM)

You just need to use a correct format to solve this e.g,

```
{{ '2019-08-20' | date_modify('-3 day') | date('d-m-Y') }}
{{ '08/20/2019' | date_modify('-3 day') | date('d-m-Y') }}
{{ '08/20/2019' | date_modify('-3 day') | date('d/m/Y') }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/p33i5z/2)

Comment: Hi DarkBee, thank you. Sadly, it still doesn't seem to be working. DD and MM are still the wrong way round.

Comment: I agree. I think the issue is the date array is being pulled from a URL Param and the |date_modify function presumes the date pulled is in MM/DD/YYYY format.

Comment: Well you will need to swap the day and month around yes if you are using `/`'s